# Getting nth-child with an offset in PHP with modulus

Tags: php, loops, modulus

When iterating through a loop, I've used the modulus operator in an `if` statement to obtain `nth` results pretty easily like this:

```
// Get 5th item in series
if ($variable->array_item % 5 == 0) {
  echo $variable->array_item;
}
```

How do you do get the 5th item in a series with an offset of 3 (ie, 3,8,13,18,23,etc.)?

I've seen a couple of methods but I'm looking for a canonical answer and I really don't see one on S.O. right now.

Comment: When you say, "How do you do it with an offset", could you clarify what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: Updated question - hope its clearer now. Modulus doesnt seem to play nice with offsets.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the end of the week and I'm probably just missing something screamingly obvious because I still don't understand your question. Do you mean "I want the 3rd, 8th, 13th, 18th items"?

Comment: Ha, right? I'm near the end too! I'm trying to get the fifth result with an offset of three. So 3,8,13,18,23, etc.

Comment: I understand now; I've posted an answer that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code specifically requests numbers that are evenly divisible by 5, whereas what you want are numbers 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, etc. This is easy enough to do using almost identical code to what you have:

```
// set up some test data
$testArray = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 30; ++$i) {
    $testArray[$i] = "Testing {$i}";
}

// here's where the actual work happens
foreach ($testArray as $key => $value) {
    if ($key % 5 == 3) { // <-- note 3, not 0
        echo "Found $value\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting method, I will give this a shot.

Answer (score 1):

```
$iterator = 0;
$step = 3;

while($iterator < count($collection))
{
 echo $collection[$iterator]
 $iterator += $step
}
```